# Finding the permutation that satisfy given condition

Tags: c++, algorithm, count, permutation

I want to find out the number of all permutation of `n`number.Number will be from `1` to `n`.The given condition is that each `ith`position can have number up to `Si`,where `Si` is given for each position of number.

```
1<=n<=10^6
1<=si<=n
```

For example:

```
n=5
```

then its all five element will be

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

and given Si for each position is as:

```
2,3,4,5,5
```

It shows that at: 
`1st` position can have `1 to 2`that is `1,2` but can not be number among `3 to 5`.
Similarly,
 At `2nd` position can have number `1 to 3` only.
 At `3rd` position can have number `1 to 4` only.
 At `4th` position can have number `1 to 5` only.
 At `5th` position can have number `1 to 5` only.
Some of its permutation are:

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,1,4,5
2,3,4,1,5 etc.
```

But these can not be:

```
3,1,4,2,5  As 3 is present at 1st position.
1,2,5,3,4  As 5 is present at 3rd position.
```

I am not getting any idea to count all possible number of permutations with given condition.

Comment: Is this some coding contest?or judge problem?

Comment: It does not belongs to any running coding contest.But it requires for my coding implementation.

Comment: @coderredoc Given limits for n and Si is already mentioned.

Comment: Do you need *only the number* of permutations or the permutations themselves too? And for your example, how much exactly permutation would be possible?

Comment: @Yuriy only the number of permutation.

Comment: @Enigma do we have a guarantee that numbers `si` are given in *not descending* order?

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych Yes it is guarantee that numbers si are given in not descending order.

Comment: @Enigma then looks like I've found O(n) in time for your problem - checkout my answer. Btw for your example `si = {2,3,4,5,5}` looks like the answer is 16, am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135975/discussion-between-enigma-and-yuriy-ivaskevych).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if we have a guarantee that numbers `si` are given in *not descending* order then looks like it is possible to calculate the number of permutations in `O(n)`.

The idea of straightforward algorithm is as follows:

1. At step `i` multiply the result by *current* value of `si[i]`;
2. We chose some number for position `i`. As long as we need permutation, that number cannot be repeated, so decrement all the rest `si[k]` where `k` from `i+1` to the end (e.g. `n`) by 1;
3. Increase `i` by 1, go back to (1).

To illustrate on example for `si: 2 3 3 4`:

1. `result = 1`;
2. current `si` is "2 3 3 4", `result *= si[0]` (= 1*2 == 2), decrease 3, 3 and 4 by 1;
3. current `si` is "..2 2 3", `result *= si[1]` (= 2*2 == 4), decrease last 2 and 3 by 1;
4. current `si` is "....1 2", `result *= si[2]` (= 4*1 == 4), decrease last number by 1;
5. current `si` is "..... 1", `result *= si[3]` (= 4*1 == 4), done.

Hovewer this straightforward approach would require `O(n^2)` due to decreasing steps. To optimize it we can easily observe that at the moment of `result *= si[i]` our si[i] was already decreased exactly `i` times (assuming we start from 0 of course).

Thus `O(n)` way:

```
unsigned int result = 1;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    result *= (si[i] - i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for each si count the number of element in your array such that a[i] <= si using binary search, and store the value to an array count[i], now the answer is the product of all count[i], however we have decrease the number of redundancy from the answer ( as same number could be count twice ), for that you can sort si and check how many number is <= s[i], then decrease that number from each count,the complexity is O(nlog(n)), hope at least I give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Yuriy Ivaskevych answer, if you don't know if the sis are in increasing order, you can sort the sis and it will also works.
And the result will be null or negative if the permutations are impossible (ex: 1 1 1 1 1)

Answer (score -1):

You can try backtracking, it's a little hardcore approach but will work.
try:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/backtracking-example/
or google backtracking tutorial C++

Comment: n is up to 1e6, this will got TLE, even O(n^2) will get TLE.

Comment: @Alex Banu, I know little about backtracking, please explain how to implement backtracking for this question.